# Why Google Places API autocomplete works in localhost but not after firebase deploy?

Tags: reactjs, google-maps, google-places-api

I've been trying to add an autocomplete toto html form and when I try in localhost works correctly but after deploy to firebase autocomplete are not showing any option.

Our google cloud API is not app restricted and API restricted in: 
Places API
Maps JavaScript API
Geolocation API
Geocoding API

That is how I include the aPI in my index.html:

```
   <script async defer src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=API-KEY&libraries=places" type="text/javascript"></script>
```

And here the implementation in other react component:

```
  // @ts-ignore
  const google = window.google;

  if (google) {
    google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, 'load', cityInput);
  }
```

```
cont input = document.getElementById('city') as HTMLInputElement;
const types = { types: ['(cities)'], componentRestrictions: { country: 'es' } }
const autocomplete = new google.maps.places.Autocomplete(input, types);
```

```
 <input
          readOnly={this.props.readonly}
          id={this.props.id} // city
          className="input"
          onBlur={this.handleChange}
          onKeyUp={this.handleChange}
          placeholder={this.props.placeholder}
          defaultValue={this.props.value}
        />
```

Any idea to test something or change something ?

Thank you all.

Comment: Please could you share the full error log you're getting?